# How to read the content of zipped file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form like this

```
<input type="file" name="zip" size="20"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

I want to upload( POST) a zip file with this form and in my controller i want to read the content of this zipped file , also i search but i found nothing .
Any ideas?

Comment: If the framework doesn't provide this you can use the features built in the language http://php.net/zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest following steps

1. Upload the file ([How to](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html))
2. Extract the zip file to a temporary location ([How to](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php))
3. List temporary folder content to get zip file content ([How to](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php))